# Can't upload file to aws s3 asp.net

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
 fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    FilePath = filePath,
                    StorageClass = S3StorageClass.StandardInfrequentAccess,
                    PartSize = 6291456, // 6 MB.  
                    Key = keyName,
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
                };
                fileTransferUtilityRequest.Metadata.Add("param1", "Value1");
                fileTransferUtilityRequest.Metadata.Add("param2", "Value2");
                fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
                fileTransferUtility.Dispose();
            }
```

Im getting this error
**The file indicated by the FilePath property does not exist!**

I tried changing the path to the actual path of the file to C:\Users\jojo\Downloads but im still getting the same error.

Comment: What is the `file` variable?  This looks like something handling a file upload in a web application and you may be confusing it with the file on your local computer.  Perhaps it's saved to a temp location on the web server?  Or needs to be saved to a temp location before being used here?

Comment: I would suggest you to check first the file existence by this File.Exists(FilePath) then you might get the actual issue or may be your file location.

Comment: @David the file variable is from **public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)**

Answer (score 1):

(Based on a comment above indicating that `file` is an instance of `HttpPostedFileBase` in a web application...)

I don't know where you got `Server.MapPath("~/Files")` from, but if `file` is an `HttpPostedFileBase` that's been uploaded to this web application code then it's likely in-memory and not on your file system.  Or at best it's on the file system in a temp system folder somewhere.

Since your source (the `file` variable contents) is a stream, before you try to interact with the file system you should see if the AWS API you're using can accept a stream.  [And it looks like it can.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtility_Upload_1.htm)

```
if (file.ContentLength > 0)
{
    var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(/* constructor params here */);
    transferUtility.Upload(file.InputStream, bucketName, keyName);
}
```

Note that this is entirely free-hand, I'm not really familiar with AWS interactions.  And you'll definitely want to take a look at the constructors on `TransferUtility` to see which one meets your design.  But the point is that you're currently looking to upload a *stream* from the file you've already uploaded to your web application, *not* looking to upload an actual file from the file system.

---

As a fallback, if you can't get the stream upload to work (and you really should, that's the ideal approach here), then your next option is likely to save the file first and then upload it using the method you have now.  So if you're expecting it to be in `Server.MapPath("~/Files")` then you'd need to save it to that folder first, for example:

```
file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)));
```

Of course, over time this folder can become quite full and you'd likely want to clean it out.